# As a developer, how do you delete an app from the AppStore that you had previously submitted and is available through iTunes?

Tags: app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

We'd created an app, submitted it to the AppStore, now we're looking to make it unavailable through iTunes for further downloads. There isn't an intuitive way to do this through iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not intuitive at all, but deleting your app from iTunesConnect in Apple speak is "disabling further sales of your app." From the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html):

Removing an App From Sale

To remove your app from sale on the App Store:
1. Click on the  button from your App Summary Page.
2. Click on the  button to uncheck all App Store territories.
3. Click on the  button.

After removing all assigned territory checkboxes from your app in the Rights and Pricing section, the status changes to Developer Removed from Sale and your app will not be seen on the App Store within 24 hours

Comment: hint: you can accept your own answer to mark it answered and also get some reputation points.

Comment: After you have removed it from sale in all territories, the "Delete Application" link becomes available under the same links as "Rights and Pricing". --> you can only delete if you have removed from all territories first.

Comment: Why would you like to delete an app from the Apple store? And if you change your mind after that can you undelete it or return it to the store again?